# How to Navigate to Screen inside Action Creators with React Navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

In [React Navigation 5 Auth Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/), it says screen will automatically navigate when conditional state changes.

- I have setup the screen to navigate to HomeScreen when the state of
  isAuthenticated changes to true.
- There is no error in the console. The isAuthenticated does change to
  true, but the screen is not navigating to HomeScreen after state
  change.
- I also tried using alternatives like {NavigationActions} and
  {CommonActions} in the action creators. to force navigation, but are
  also not working.

AuthStackNav.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AuthScreen from '../screens/AuthScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';

const AuthStackNav = ({isAuthenticated}) => {
    const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

    return (        
        <AuthStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Auth'>
        {
            isAuthenticated ?
            <AuthStack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />                
            :
            <AuthStack.Screen  name='Auth' component={AuthScreen} />      
        }                       
                         
        </AuthStack.Navigator>
        
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = ({isAuthenticated}) => {
    return {isAuthenticated};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AuthStackNav);
```

userActions.js

```js
import {LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK} from './types';
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation'; 
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native'; 

export const loginWithFacebook = () => (dispatch) => {        
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK, payload: {isAuthenticated: true} });   
    dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'Home'}));
    dispatch( CommonActions.navigate({ name: 'Home' }) );                                           
};
```

userReducer.js

```js
import {LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK} from '../actions/types.js';

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false    
};

const userReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK: 
            return {...state, ...action.payload};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
export default userReducer;
```

AuthScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {loginWithFacebook} from '../actions/userActions';

const AuthScreen = ({loginWithFacebook}) => {    

    return (
        <View style={styles.screenContainer}>                

                <TouchableOpacity                     
                    activeOpacity={0.5}
                    onPress={loginWithFacebook}
                >  Facebook Login</TouchableOpacity> 

        </View>  
    );
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loginWithFacebook
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthScreen);
```

AppNav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthStackNav from './AuthStackNav';

const AppNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthStackNav />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default AppNav;
```

Comment: By disconnecting, is it goes to `Auth` es expected? maybe it just `initialRouteName='Auth'`...

Comment: @HagaiHarari Hi, yes initial screen is AuthScreen

Comment: @HagaiHarari I tried removing the initialRouteName='Auth', it still doesn't work. I also tried using alternatives like {NavigationActions} and {CommonActions} in the action creators. to force navigation, but also not working.

Comment: import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'Home'}));

Comment: import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.navigate({
    name: 'Home'    
  })
);

Comment: On which `navigation` you implemented `dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'Home'}))`?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I implemented it below the dispatch payload inside this action creator. 
export const loginWithFacebook = () => (dispatch) => {        
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK, payload: {isAuthenticated: true} });                                              
};

Comment: Its two different `dispatch`... there is dispatch of redux, and there is `navigation.dispatch(navigationActions....)`

Comment: You can `console.log(navigation)` anywhere at your app and see it have it own `dispatch` method unrelated to this word of redux ecosystem

Comment: @HagaiHarari I used the redux dispatch method to dispatch the NavigationActions

Comment: How did you invoke loginWithFacebook()?

Comment: @arjayosma It is invoked in AuthScreen.js 
<TouchableOpacity onPress={loginWithFacebook}> Login with Facebook</TouchableOpacity>

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loginWithFacebook
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthScreen);

Comment: `loginWithFacebook` came from props in this case? since you passed the dispatch to props


I believe it should be `props.loginWithFacebook()` or `onPress={props.loginWithFacebook}` if you did not destructure the props @Kevin

Comment: @arjayosma yes it came from connect props
 const AuthScreen = ({loginWithFacebook}) => {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve it with this [guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/).

RootNavigation.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

AppNav.js

```
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation.js';
const AppNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} >
            <AuthStackNav />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default AppNav;
```

userActions.js

```
export const loginWithFacebook = () => (dispatch) => {        
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK, payload: {isAuthenticated: true} });   
    RootNavigation.navigate('Home');                                    
};
```

Comment: Great! You really save me with the answer. In all foruns thats I search for a solution I just found ways to do this with the React navigation 4.x, which is deprecated today.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Kaizen Tamashi is correct.
In addition, if you want the **goBack** functionality just add this code inside RootNavigation.js

```
export function goBack() {
  navigationRef.current?.goBack();
}
```